# How to dynamically create a SQL SELECT request using Javascript then execute it with Ajax

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

So here is my problem:

I need to get information from my database (MySQL) through filters applied with checkbox.

As a constraint I must do it in javascript then use Ajax to execute the request.

It would have been with radio input that would have been fine, but as it is checkbox I cannot determine in advance how many filter my user will have when getting the information they want.

I was thinking of creating a string that would be a concatenation of the filters I need but I'm not sure if it is good practice nor if it would be security breach :( (which is definitely BAD for that project)

here is an exemple of what I'd like to do:

```
[ ] a [x] b [ ] c
```

then my SQL request should be:

```
SELECT 'column' FROM 'table' WHERE 'id' = b
```

and in this case

```
[x] a [ ] b [x] c
```

then my SQL request should be:

```
SELECT 'column' FROM 'table' WHERE 'id' = a OR 'id' = c
```

I hope this does help you understand what I'm looking for.

And do not hesitate if you need more information!!

Thank you in advance =)

Comment: Don't ever, EVER build SQL queries on the client side. That means that your database will be open to running arbitrary queries by _anyone_. A malicious user could trick the browser into sending, for example, `SELECT password FROM user` (or worse if the DB user has write privileges).

Comment: That what I was worried about :/ thank you for your answer. so then how should i get my filter into the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't build SQL queries on the client side. That means that your database will be open to running arbitrary queries by anyone. A malicious user could trick the browser into sending, for example, SELECT password FROM user (or worse if the DB user has write privileges).

Instead you should send your query parameters to your server as plain URL parameters. For example,

`GET /query?a=true&b=false&c=true`

Your server should extract the parameters, validate them (so that only known parameters, and only valid values for those parameters are accepted), and build a **safe** SQL query with **properly escaped inputs** using a proven query building library or SQL [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

How you do that depends on the platform that your server software uses. For example, in Node.js:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = ? AND b = ? AND c = ?', [validatedA, validatedB, validatedC], function(err, results) {
  // ...
});
```

The `mysql` library takes care of correctly escaping the parameters to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

The MySQL library for your backend platform will have a similar function.

There are many other questions that touch on this subject. For example (both about PHP but the advice applies to any platform): [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [Best Way to Secure SQL Query in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062194/best-way-to-secure-sql-query-in-php).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation and your help, allow me  to mark this as answered then =)